# Visual Studio update 15.7.2 breaks Xamarin Android project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, telerik

After updating Visual Studio, I can no longer build the release version of my Xamarin project:

> 1>Foobar.Android ->
>   C:\Apps\foobar-telerik-mobile-app\foobar\Android\bin\Release\foobar.Android.dll
> 1>No
>   way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e".
>   Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
> 1>The
>   "LinkAssemblies" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
> 1>Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
>   'System.Void
>   Telerik.XamarinForms.DataGrid.RadDataGridResourceDictionary::InitializeComponent()'
>   in assembly: 'Telerik.XamarinForms.DataGrid.dll' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   System.Func`2
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ResourceLoader::get_ResourceProvider()

If the Android option "Use Shared Runtime" is true, it will build - except you cannot publish with that option set! So there is no point.

I have no idea how to fix this. Any Microsoft/Xamarin/Telerik insiders out there with some ideas?

Comment: Try to set linking option in Android project properties to "None" to see if it works.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Can't say thanks enough!

Comment: No problem. A disadvantage of setting linking option to none is an increase in app's file size. though it can be resolved by different options such as configuring "proguard" .

Comment: Yes, the size has more than doubled. I am playing around with these options now.

Comment: I'm having exact same issue - existing Xamarin.Forms projects which were working now do not, even a brand new project has tons of errors out of the box (https://drive.google.com/open?id=17y-8tfJ5eJmp-JfBF8h0QlezioUHgSpz).  But... your solution of setting linking to "none" won't work for me as the setting seems to already be set that way.  Other ideas?

Comment: @Donna The first common option that comes to mind in such situations is cleaning whole solution, deleting obj/bin folders, and even maybe deleting .vs folder.

Comment: Microsoft broke Telerik's code, and Telerik is working on a fix. https://www.telerik.com/forums/mono-linker-markexception#PoC2yYwMIkuNHyucYcVjoQ https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2835. Or maybe the Xamarin people are working on it. Not sure.

Comment: @Gerry my project builds, but at runtime crashes on App.xaml.cs's call to InializeComponent. The innerexception gives an InvalidCastException but not a whole lot else. I use Telerik also, and Prism. Have you seen anything like this in your findings? Any advice on getting more information about my error? The logs don't seem to show anything either.

Comment: Seen it sure, but don't remember the circumstances. You might want to try posting a question :-)