# Updating Visual Studio to 15.7.2 breaks my Xamarin Forms Android project, but not iOS

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, prism

I've needed to update Visual Studio to 15.7.2. to fix Android project cleaning crashes, and package update issues relating to Xamarin Forms 3 (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2812).

My problem now is that my previously working Android project no longer runs. As far as I know, it's a problem in the App.xaml.cs class (a subclass to PrismApplication), on the call to `InitializeComponent()`. I've wrapped it with a try/catch (as the crashed app doesn't have any exception information). I then look at the Exception e's inner exception and see that I'm getting an **InvalidCastException**. But that's all I get. There is no other information available to me in the IDE or logfiles.

What could be going wrong from this update? My entire solution is still on a very outdated Xamarin Forms 2.4. I need 15.7.2 to get around the bug which I linked to. It's crossed my mind that I could update Forms now to fix this issue, but that could be a whole different rabbit hole. I've also seen other questions about breaks that have occured from 15.7.2:

[Xamarin.Forms with Prism not building in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553196/xamarin-forms-with-prism-not-building-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-2)

[Visual Studio update 15.7.2 breaks Xamarin Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492630/visual-studio-update-15-7-2-breaks-xamarin-android-project)

Comment: [configure VS to stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) at the InvalidCastException

Comment: Clean you solution, delete bin and obj folder, then rebuild again.